# wxpython change image size and position

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to add an image to my interface, but the picture is simply too big and I don't know how to change the size or the position.

I can only show the picture, but the picture is too big and covers everything. So here is the code:

```
self.png = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.Bitmap("image.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to use a copy of your image, `resized` as appropriate.
However, you can use `wx.Image` which provides options `Scale` or `Rescale` along with `Resize`, `Rotate` etc.
For example:

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.MaxImageSize = 500
        self.Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.Bitmap(self.MaxImageSize, self.MaxImageSize))
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(self.Image, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(box)

        Img = wx.Image('image/pia21970-opt.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
# scale the image, keeping ratio
        W = Img.GetWidth()
        H = Img.GetHeight()
        print("Actual image size Width",W,"Height",H)
        if W > H:
            NewW = self.MaxImageSize
            NewH = self.MaxImageSize * H / W
        else:
            NewH = self.MaxImageSize
            NewW = self.MaxImageSize * W / H
        print("New image size Width",NewW,"Height",NewH)
        Img = Img.Scale(NewW,NewH,quality=wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        self.Image.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(Img))
        self.Show()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = TestFrame(None, -1, "wxBitmap Test")
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: combining the ability to scale an image with a bit of judicious mouse scrolling can provide a Zoom control.

[image]

Positioning can be achieved using the form `pos=(x,y)` if not using `sizers` otherwise the `sizer` controls the position and you control the `sizer`.